# How to Migrate Assigned Connect App thing in Permission set?

Tags: deployment, salesforce-id, ant, permission-sets

We have assigned `DataLoader Bulk`, `Dataloader Partner` & `Workbench` connected app to a permission set in our DEV sandbox.

But while retrieving permission set using below `package.xml` (with ant), there is no mention of connected app assignment in Permission set meta file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Vijay_Permit</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Vijay_Permit</members>
        <name>ConnectedApp</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. Connected Apps are assigned with the junction object `SetupEntityAccess`. This is a data relationship, not metadata. Yes it's a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

The connection between `Connected App` and `Permission Set` is defined inside `Connected App` metadata file in `PermissionSetName` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <canvasConfig>
        <accessMethod>Post</accessMethod>
        <canvasUrl>https://google.com/</canvasUrl>
        <locations>Visualforce</locations>
        <locations>Aura</locations>
        <samlInitiationMethod>None</samlInitiationMethod>
    </canvasConfig>
    <contactEmail>google@google.com</contactEmail>
    <label>Connected App</label>
    <oauthConfig>
        <callbackUrl>Https://google.com</callbackUrl>
        <isAdminApproved>true</isAdminApproved>
        <scopes>Full</scopes>
        <scopes>RefreshToken</scopes>
    </oauthConfig>
    <permissionSetName>Permission Set</permissionSetName>
    <profileName>Some Profile</profileName> 
</ConnectedApp>
```